# notification gateway or hub

Tags: notification, integrations

I'm looking to a product that could relay notifications from an application hosted on a server to a number of channels like Whatsapp, Telegram, Discord, Slack etc.

Preferably open source so I can tinker with it.

I've made some research on the web, on github and here, with no result. Mainly point to point integration, like send notification to slack, but no hub.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More focused researches lead to some candidates (see other answers).

The most appropriate to my needs was [apprise](https://hub.docker.com/r/caronc/apprise) ([sources](https://github.com/caronc/apprise)), in Python, load of [providers](https://github.com/caronc/apprise#popular-notification-services).

It can be used as a python library or as an HTTP API.

Notification channel are in the configuration (or can be hard-coded, not my choice).

Configuration can be described in a YAML file, using URL, one format per provider, like `telegram://...`.

It has a tag mechanism that allow to route notifications to different channels.

The documentation is well done.

I managed to do all my setup in a couple of hours.

Comment: That's four answers.  Please post each separately so that they may be voted upon separately.  Also, please explain for each answer why it meets the requirements of the question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[shoutrrr](https://containrrr.dev/shoutrrr/) ([sources](https://github.com/containrrr/shoutrrr)), in Go, load of providers

Answer (score 0):

[notifire](https://www.notifire.co/) ([sources](https://github.com/notifirehq/notifire/)), in nodejs, some providers but not all the ones I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

[messageraft](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@messageraft/cli) ([sources](https://github.com/messageraft/messageraft-server)), in nodejs, very few providers